# При нажатии на div, показать другой div

Tags: html, jquery

Есть список ul с элементами вида li.item_1, li.item_2 и т.д. Необходимо при нажатии на элемент li показать соответствующий div.item_1, div.item_2 и т.д. Как это реализовать на Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('ul').on('click', '.li', function(e) {
  let $this = $(this);

  $(`.div.${$this.attr('class').split(/\s+/).filter(_ => _.startsWith('item_'))[0]}`).css({
    display: 'block'
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="li item_1">LI #01</li>
  <li class="li item_2">LI #02</li>
  <li class="li item_3">LI #03</li>
  <li class="li item_4">LI #04</li>
  <li class="li item_5">LI #05</li>
</ul>
<div class="div item_1">DIV #01</div>
<div class="div item_2">DIV #02</div>
<div class="div item_3">DIV #03</div>
<div class="div item_4">DIV #04</div>
<div class="div item_5">DIV #05</div>
```

Comment: В принципе это оно, но у меня классы такого вида: <li class="li item_1"></li>, <div class="div item_1"></div>. В таком случае не работает

Comment: В чём сложность модифицировать мой пример?

Comment: Обновил........